# Get Symfony2's kernel in config

Tags: php, configuration, symfony-2.3

how can I get the AppKernel obj in the php-version of the Symfony2 configuration?

I need a parameter who's set in app.php/app_dev.php

Thanks for helping!

Comment: php version of the Symfony2 configuration? Can you specify that?

Comment: No, i mean which kind of configuration are you talking about? You said "in the php-version of the Symfony2 configuration". Actually there are several/many places where you can configure things in Symfony2. E.g. show some code and the name of your configuration file.

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean the app/config.php.
I've a multi site project and I need a dynamicly configuration which sets the database connection parameters by the domain name.

I've a parameters.yml file with all the required parameters (e.g. %domain1.db_host% and %domain2.db_host%).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$container->getParameter()` to access parameters, e.g.

```
$container->getParameter('domain1.db_host')
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work. I tried it with echo $container->getParameter('the_parameter'); and I got no output.

Comment: No output means that the requested parameter is NULL / not correctly set. Do ``var_dump($container->getParameterBag())`` to see all parameters. How do you set the parameter in app_dev.php?

Comment: I override the function getKernelParameters() from Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php

But now I've found another solution to solve my problem. I'm using different environments. Thanks for helping!